# Why doesn't Protobuf-net typemodel serialize private readonly members?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have the following class which I would like to build a protobuf-net typemodel for:

```
      [DataContract]
      public class Currency
      {
          [DataMember(Order = 0)]
          private readonly string code;

          public Currency(string code)
          {
              // Initialize members
              this.code = code;
          }

          public string Code
          {
              get { return this.code; }
          }
      }
```

I set up the type model as follows:

```
  var model = TypeModel.Create();
  var typeInModel = model.Add(typeof(Currency), true);
  typeInModel.UseConstructor = false;
```

When I look at the "fields" member in the type model after adding this type, I do not see anything there for the code member. What am I missing here?

UPDATE: Can now create type model but serialization still doesn't work.

Comment: http://marcgravell.blogspot.de/2011/08/automatic-serialization-whats-in-tuple.html

Comment: I'm not at a PC right now; with the 0 => 1 edit it should work fine, but I will check later. Can I ask: what platform are you using? Regular .net? Silverlight? XNA? What?

Answer (score 1):

My colleague found that if you change the DataMember order from:

```
  [DataMember(Order = 0)]
```

to:

```
  [DataMember(Order = 1)]
```

that everything suddenly works fine for building the type model, though serialization still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your code, as written (with the `[DataMember(Order=1)]` fix from your answer) works fine. The following:

```
var obj = new Currency("abc");
var clone = (Currency) model.DeepClone(obj);

Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(obj, clone));
Console.WriteLine(clone.Code);
```

outputs

```
False
abc
```

exactly as I would expect - meaning: different object instance, but created successfully with the right values.

If you are doing something different, please let me know. Also note, as per the comment, that reflection to private members is limited on some platforms - most notably Silverlight and Phone 7.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My colleague was looking into it while I was on hols, and says it looks like the problem was happening because we were compiling the model before using it.

Answer (score 0):

When running WCF code in Partial Trust mode, the serialization and deserialization of readonly fields (both public and private) is not supported. This is because the generated IL is unverifiable and therefore requires elevated permissions.

Take a look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Although I am using the DataContract / DataMember attributes, I'm not actually using WCF at all in my scenario. I am using a protobuf serialization library for .net which can also make use of these attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Something in the serialize process skips properties that have no setters.

It seems like a bit of a hack, but I usually do this:

```
[DataMember]
public string Code {
    get { return this.code; }
    set { }
}
```

Once the set is there, even though it does nothing, it'll be picked up in the serialization process.

Comment: ah! Nice! I will give this a try and see how it goes :)

Comment: I may have mis-read initially... you are trying to serialize a variable, but generally serialization happens on the properties themselves. This should still work, but you'll likely need to add [DataMember] decorator to your public string Code property